# Could not find CMake package configuration file for "Eigen3"

Tags: cmake, osx-mavericks, ros

When I enter this command:

```
cd /Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros && /Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

I receive this error:

```
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/mona/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

This command is ran as part of running this command for installing `ROS`:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Any idea how that could be fixed?

Please see more details of question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/215080/how-to-add-the-installation-prefix-of-eigen3-to-cmake_prefix_path-or-set-eigen3_dir-to-a-directory-containing-one-of-the-above-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install Eigen3. It provides the FindEigen3.cmake file. The error occurs because the project you want to configure, has a dependency to Eigen3.

If you have Eigen3 installed, follow the error message and add Eigen3 to CMake's search path.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide me with more detail like the command for installing the Eigen3? I installed the tar.gz file from eigen site and followed the items told to me in INSTALL file but yet can figure it out. You can read more on what I did here. Any help is really appreciated. http://answers.ros.org/question/215080/how-to-add-the-installation-prefix-of-eigen3-to-cmake_prefix_path-or-set-eigen3_dir-to-a-directory-containing-one-of-the-above-files/

Comment: You can always manually copy the FindEigen3.cmake file in your current project. Or you can add the path to the file in your search path.

Answer (score 8):

For linux users, this may help like it did for me: just install the developers' package of the eigen3 lib by the following command.

`sudo apt install libeigen3-dev`

Answer (score 0):

don't need to build and install Eigen3 from source files.
just install it using apt on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in my case

sudo apt install libeigen3-dev

and check the installed path like the below

dpkg -L libeigen3-dev

....

```
/usr/share/eigen3
/usr/share/eigen3/cmake  <--- you can find this path
/usr/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake
/usr/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3ConfigVersion.cmake
/usr/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3Targets.cmake
```

and add it to CMakeLists.txt

```
set(Eigen3_DIR /usr/share/eigen3/cmake)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
```