# Including library with cmake manually

Tags: c++, cmake, include

In the cluster of my uni I do not have sudo rights, and I need the version `Eigen3 3.3.3` and they only offer `Eigen 2.8` installed.

Now, I uploaded the source files of `Eigen3 3.3.3` and tried to manually hook it up with `cmake`.

Then I set the environmental variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` accordingly. In `cmake` I have set the requirements as:

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.3.3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

But I get this error message:

> By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
>   project has   asked CMake to find a package configuration file
>   provided by "Eigen3", but   CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3"
>   (requested   version 3.3.3) with any of the following names:

---

I don't understand why I have to manually provide a `FindEigen3.cmake` file? Usually, one has not to do it. How to solve this error? I do not want to manipulate the existing `CMakeList.txt`. Thanks.

Comment: The library brings its own CMake configuration script. The CMake needs a hint where your `Eigen3` library is to configure it correctly (see  [`cmake/FindEigen3.cmake`](https://github.com/OPM/eigen3/blob/master/cmake/FindEigen3.cmake)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find Eigen3 with CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138879/unable-to-find-eigen3-with-cmake)

Comment: @Florian I have seen it already. But I can't imagine to take care of it with `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` by myself. Especially, I do not want to manipulate an existing `CMakeFiles.txt` to conform eigen3.

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/path/to/Eigen3/cmake ..`

Comment: @Florian alright, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

The library brings its own [CMake configuration script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#config-file-packages). The CMake needs a hint where your Eigen3 library is to configure it correctly (see [`cmake/FindEigen3.cmake`](https://github.com/OPM/eigen3/blob/master/cmake/FindEigen3.cmake)).

So you can define the search path in your [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) command line call:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/path/to/Eigen3/cmake ..
```

**References**

- [Unable to find Eigen3 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138879/unable-to-find-eigen3-with-cmake)
- [Could not find CMake package configuration file for "Eigen3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774034/could-not-find-cmake-package-configuration-file-for-eigen3)